# How to initialize an object outside of main?

Tags: c++

I have the below piece of code. I want to create an object Model outside my main and then use it inside main method. However, VS keeps confusing my object initialization with a function declaration and doesnt allow me to use it. Is there a way to initialize it without the compiler confusing between the two?

```
Model model();

int main{
    model.loadModel("testModel.txt"); // I want to do st like this, but it causes error
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this line:

```
Model model();
```

will be parsed to a function declaration, this is the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You need

```
Model model;
```

or

```
Model model{};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Model model();
```

To the compiler this looks like a function declaration that returns a `Model` and takes no parameters.

Try removing the `()`:

```
Model model;
```